# Starting and stopping a script after a certain time, from a script

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I'm new to bash scripting and i have a problem i cannot solve or find the answer to, if this is the wrong place to post then i apologize.

The goal with this script is to check the condition on an external modem(continuously).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0
COUNT=0
read_serial() {    
timeout 15 ./test-read.sh 2>&1
sleep 10    
}
while true; do
echo  "Testing ""AT"" on $PORT for the $COUNT time"
echo -e "at\r" > $PORT
read_serial
COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
done
```

The read script is:

## !/bin/bash

```
set -e
echo "Reading from serial port"
cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0
wait
```

What i'm trying to do is send a simple "at", then start another script that reads the output, close that script. Then the idea is to check if the modem responds "OK" or "ERROR". I could get this working by creating two scripts but that feels messy.

```
So my questions are:
1. Is it possible to start another script, from a script for a short period of time? When i run it, timeout shuts the whole thing down.
2. Is this approach wrong?
```

Best Regards,
Willie

Comment: I don't think this approach is wrong, as long as you're getting the result you're after. However - in my experience simple is best. Are you doing this for monitoring purposes? In which case this can be simplified with `cron`. There is no reason that you couldn't execute the commands in your `second` script within your `first` script. Ultimately if you're getting certain output that you want to conditionally action - `if` and `case` would do the job for you.

Comment: Yes it is for monitoring, the serial interface sometimes "freezes" and i would like to know when that occurs. I put the second script in a function thank you!